# Getting Image Height with FancyBox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm having trouble creating an If/then in fancybox, using the height of an image that will be going into the fancybox.

```
setBigImage : function ( slide ) {
var self = this;
var $img = $('<img />');

slide.$image = $img
.one('error', function() {

self.setError( slide );

})
.one('load', function() {

slide.width  = this.naturalWidth;
slide.height = this.naturalHeight;

.addClass( 'fancybox-image ' )
.attr('src', slide.src)
.appendTo( slide.$content );
```

In essence, I'm looking to add an if/then before the .addClass call that checks to see if the image's height is greater than 500px. I have tried to use:

```
if ( slide.Width > 500)
and if ( this.NaturalHeight > 500)
```

Neither worked. I tried both slide.Width and this.NaturalHeight inside of p tags to see what text they were putting out. Unfortunately, they created a second instance of the image. What would be the best way to get the image's height?

Thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let the clarify this misunderstanding - " Unfortunately, they created a second instance of the image". When using some basic lightbox script, user would see black overlay with loading icon right after clicking thumbnail and then the image would just pop in. But fancybox displays thumbnail (first image) while actual image is still loading. Then real image (2nd image) gradually appears over the first one and user most likely will not see or notice loading indicator.

The answer to your question is also simple, just replace

`if ( slide.Width > 500)`

with

`if ( slide.width > 500)`

btw, next version of fancybox will allow more customization based on image size, see these demos - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqQLVm?editors=1010 and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPQjbw?editors=1010